# user level api 19 failed to load. What files should i download

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-sdk-2.3

user level api 19 failed to load.. When i am trying to download API 19 from sdk manager. there are 5 files to download. these are huge files. i have slow Internet question. can you tell me specific one file to download which can solve my problem. thanks.

Comment: its a whole folder that you need to download isn't it?you could just set your target sdk lower and work the time being.Or are you using and 19 specific APIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download SDK Platform Only, x86 images too if you wanna run this API on Emulator.

Cheers
-AmniX